# Single JavaScript (library) to fix all IE 6 issues and make it compatible with css3

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, css

Is there any JavaScript (library) or any other solution, through which we can fix most of IE6 issues like PNG fix and also make IE6 to support CSS3 properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. CSS3 support in IE6 is not going to happen. There is library available that will make IE6 more-or-less compatible with IE7:

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: Thanks! It will definitely helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** No.

**A little bit longer answer:** While you can cobble together pieces of code here and there that help you get most of what you want in IE6, the problem is that none of these technologies out there are perfect (with most PNG fixes - try using transparent PNGs on a background image and change the background image by changing a class). There may be solutions for rounded corners or shadows but they will likely be glitchy too.

Many JavaScript frameworks offer nearly complete JavaScript feature-support for IE6, but the case is not the same for CSS.  Many things in advanced CSS (2 and 3) will never be possible in IE6, but have to be achieved in different ways.  There is no `content` property, `:hover` only works on anchor tags, attribute-based pseudo selectors don't work.

Even technologies like GWT that compile seamlessly to JavaScript for all browsers offer conditional CSS so that you can code your own hacks or graceful degradation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) goes a long way toward resolving IE6 issues because the library tries for cross-browser compatibility and deals with CSS. At least there might not be a better option.

You might check the [Test Swarm for jQuery](http://testswarm.com/user/jqueryui/) to see where the IE6 tests are at.

Answer (score 1):

Late in the game but http://css3pie.com/ should help people looking for an alternative

> PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-8 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and other popular frameworks handle many cross browser compatibility options but won't address PNG transparency, most unsupported CSS3 etc.

If you want to take it a step up though, [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) is an option, however this has to be installed on client computers.